# SqlAlchemy sessions get stuck when not using them

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm having a hard time implementing a "MySqlClient" class for my application. My application consists of several modules which have to make use of my database & some of the modules are running on other threads.

My intention is to make an instance for every module that needs to communicate with my MySql database. For example: every client connecting to a websocket server creates his own instance, a telegram bot client has its own instance, ..

I've been searching for days now, I've read the docs, searched the forums .. but somehow I'm missing something or I'm not implementing it the right way.

This is my class:

```
class MySqlClient():

    engine = None
    Session = None

    def __init__(self):     

        # create engine
        if MySqlClient.engine == None:
            MySqlClient.engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}".format(
                state.config["mysql"]["user"],
                state.config["mysql"]["password"],
                state.config["mysql"]["host"],
                state.config["mysql"]["database"]
            ))
            MySqlClient.Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=MySqlClient.engine))
            Base.metadata.create_all(MySqlClient.engine)

        self.session = MySqlClient.Session()

    def get_budget(self, budget_id):   
        try:

            q = self.session.query(
                (Budget.amount).label("budgetAmount"), 
                func.sum(BudgetRecord.amount).label("total")
                ).all().filter(Budget.id == budget_id).join(BudgetRecord).filter(extract("month", BudgetRecord.ts) == datetime.datetime.now().month)
            self.session.close()

            return { "budgetAmount": q[0].budgetAmount, "total": 0.0 if q[0].total == None else q[0].total }

        except Exception as ex:
            logging.error(ex)

        return None
```

When I start my application everything runs fine, I can execute the method "get_budget" returning the data. However, if after this I wait for 5 minutes, the method won't run again (if I don't wait, it still works). After about 15 minutes after I made the call, the query finally fails saying the MySql connection has dropped:

```
(mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) MySQL Connection not available.
```

I also tried getting a new session before executing new queries. That didn't help either.

I've done things like this before but it's the first time I'm using an ORM & I'd like to keep the benefits of using ORM.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Regards

Comment: Not relevant to your question but you should consider putting a lock around the `if MySqlClient.engine == None:` part as there is a race condition there.

Comment: Does it fail when a single thread running? Or only when multiple threads running?

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue. Ran 2 threads, each would instantiate a `MySqlClient` instance (once only), call `get_budget()` and sleep for 5 minutes before calling `get_budget()` again. Both threads successfully returned a result from the query 5 times before I killed it. Why are you so sure that it is the session causing the problem? If you can provide a copy/paste example that reproduces the issue, I'll have another go at it.

Comment: It also fails when I only use 1 client in the application (i commented out the others). Because you asked why I thought this is session related. I started to think it might be network related. 

I just changed the mysql connection string to a local IP address instead of a dyndns adress and that solved the issue! I thought session objects get recycled when faulty? Also, I tried making new sessions before each query, so this would make it a mysql server problem i guess.

Anyhow thanks for your help on this!